# Car only runs when I am cranking the car

Tags: spark

I have a 1973 Datsun 240k that will only run while I’m turning the key and engaging the starter. As soon as I let go of the key the car immediately dies

What would cause this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is usually a ballast resistor fault.

Some cars had a resistor mounted next to the ccoil which provided about 9v to the coil when running. When starting the coil was supplied with 12v to increase spark voltage.

On some cars the ballast resistor was a length of resistance wire built into the wiring harness.

Try putting a supply from an ignition feed source and testing again, if it runs then you need to replace the ballast resistor. Or you can fit a standard 12v coil instead.

Comment: Thanks, in my case there was a length of resistance wire that was causing the issue

Comment: Note that if you run a 9V coil on 12V constantly you'll cook the condenser inside the distributor.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica you did note that I put that one would need to replace the ballast redistor or fit a 12v coil?

Comment: What? You expected me to read the *last sentence*?!? :-}